# C++ procedure for determining whether two segments intersect

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, segments

I'm working a bit with computational geometry lately, and I am trying to find a way of checking whether two line segments intersect. I thought that I can use counterclockwise direction (CCW for short) to determine that. Here is my code so far:

```
struct point { double x, y };

double CCW(point a, point b, point c)
{ return (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (b.y-a.y)*(c.x-a.x); }

int intersect(point a, point b, point c, point d)
{ return (CCW(a,b,c)*CCW(a,b,d)<0 && CCW(c,d,b)*CCW(c,d,a)<0); }
```

The above code worked for the test cases I entered, and it's pretty readable and very easy to implement. But after searching on the web, I found an other way of solving the segment intersection problem. The code is similar to mine, but it has some more `if` statements that my implementation omits. Here is the code:

```
struct line { point s, e; };

int middle(int a, int b, int c) {
  int t;    
  if ( a > b ) {
    t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
  }
  if ( a <= c && c <= b ) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int intersect(line a, line b) {
  if ( ( CCW(a.s, a.e, b.s) * CCW(a.s, a.e, b.e) < 0 ) &&
     ( CCW(b.s, b.e, a.s) * CCW(b.s, b.e, a.e) < 0 ) ) return 1;

  if ( CCW(a.s, a.e, b.s) == 0 && middle(a.s.x, a.e.x, b.s.x) && middle(a.s.y, a.e.y, b.s.y) ) return 1;
  if ( CCW(a.s, a.e, b.e) == 0 && middle(a.s.x, a.e.x, b.e.x) && middle(a.s.y, a.e.y, b.e.y) ) return 1;
  if ( CCW(b.s, b.e, a.s) == 0 && middle(b.s.x, b.e.x, a.s.x) && middle(b.s.y, b.e.y, a.s.y) ) return 1;
  if ( CCW(b.s, b.e, a.e) == 0 && middle(b.s.x, b.e.x, a.e.x) && middle(b.s.y, b.e.y, a.e.y) ) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain which is the difference between the two implementations, and which is safer to use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you found is also checking the case where the line segments lie within the same line.  In that case, it becomes a one-dimensional problem of finding whether the two line segments overlap.  Your code would return false in this case.  Whether this is preferred or not depends on the application.

Example:

```
point a={1,0}, b={3,0}, c={2,0}, d={4,0};

intersect(a,b,c,d); // your function will return false, 
                    // but the one you found will return true
```

The function you found also looks at cases where the endpoint of one line-segment lies along the other line segment:

Example:

```
point a={1,0}, b={3,0}, c={2,0}, d={2,3};

intersect(a,b,c,d); // your function will return false, 
                    // but the one you found will return true
```